# video encoding and decoding performance compare in linux and windows

Tags: gstreamer, transcoding

I wrote a simple gstreamer pipeline to decode and re-encode h.265 to h.264: avdec_h265 | x264enc. On the same hardware, I found the cpu usage is much less in windows compared to linux. Any idea why windows transcoding is much faster in linux (Oracle 8.5)?

Comment: is it the same version of gstreamer in both windows and linux?

Comment: Both use version 1.20